# Pica8 SDN whiteswitch ping from mangement console to host port

Tags: openflow, sdn, ryu

I am connecting my controller PC to a Pica8 white switch via the Management port. I can SSH into the switch and ping the controller PC, however I cant ping the hosts through the standard ports. I have created a bridge of the first four ports and have successfully pinged from host to host after I installed a flow that allowed it.

My question is, is there some kind of mechanism separating the controller port from all of the data ports, I would think I should be able to ping from the switch to the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question, but before pinging the management port I believe you need to set an IP for it via the console port.

I use minicom per the instructions located [here](http://www.pica8.com/document/v2.6/html/picos-system-configuration/). However, I am using the RJ45 to DB9 adapter cable -> USB Serial port connection. That looks like [so](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HUZ6OMQ).

Unfortunately, that creates a problem with minicom, since the instructions tell you to simply power up the switch and observe the received data. There is actually a little more to it than that. You have to configure minicom's serial port. Fortunately, there is a [tech blog](http://lachlanmiskin.com/blog/2012/08/03/using-minicom-to-interface-with-serial-devices-on-linux/) that I found very helpful. If you follow the provided instructions, it will walk you through changing ports. Once you modify the port that minicom is listening on (For me it is Port /dev/ttyUSB0), you should be able to configure your management port.